# TFS Build Agent Output to Console

Tags: tfs

I am trying to output some text messages from Unit Tests running on a TFS Build Agent to the agent console output display.  I have tried all of these:

```
        _testContext.WriteLine($"TestContext: {text}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Hi World: {text}");
        Trace.WriteLine($"Trace the World: {text}");
        Debug.WriteLine($"Debug World: {text}");
```

within the unit test code...and they log to the Test Results file....but I would like to see some output text on the Agent Console display.  We are using TFS 2017.1 on-prem.

Is there any to do this?